# Selenium python firefox, disable images but show the placeholder

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I have followed a few other SO threads on how to disable image loading in firefox. However the page looks very messed up after disabling images. Is there a way to show the image placeholders so the page look structure wise similar to the page with images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this can't be done easily. As [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/375909) explains, if you're not actually requesting the image from the server and getting a response, the browser can't be sure how big the placeholder should be. Thus it will assume a size of {0,0}.

As usual there are lots of alternatives and workarounds, but at that point you have to decide whether the benefit of not having to download images is **really** worth the effort of: rewriting the page to replace images with fixed-size `<div>`s, rewriting the image requests using a proxy server, adding aggressive caching, etc.